# Compatibilty of OPEN VPN with CISCO ASA 5580

Tags: cisco, openvpn

Is it possible to configure/allow traffic through CISCO ASA 5580 to an OPEN VPN server using windows Active Directory authentication (Domain Users) ? 
Please share your views. 
Thanks and regards 
Somtirtha

Answer (score -1):

OpenVPN uses SSL, so it is possible to allow OpenVPN traffic through Cisco ASA. It does not matter how the OpenVPN server authenticates. If the Server is behind that Cisco ASA, just assign it a Public IP address and allow inbound traffic on Port 443.